# how to get the current page url from the web view in android

Tags: android, url, webview

Using `webview.loadUrl(url)` method I open an url. If I click any `Button` on the view it directs to another page. Now I want to get the url of the directed page. how can I get it?

I also want the content that is displayed on the webview. How to get the content of the `WebView` ?

Comment: Pls see this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/76416354/12272687

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
String webUrl = webView.getUrl();
```

Answer (score 37):

please see my answer
may it will help you...!!!!

```
WebView webview = new WebView(context);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                Log.d("WebView", "your current url when webpage loading.." + url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("WebView", "your current url when webpage loading.. finish" + url);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                System.out.println("when you click on any interlink on webview that time you got url :-" + url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am not able to get any message from any overriden method.

Comment: im also not able to see any kind of related message

Answer (score 11):

I am assuming that you have set your `WebViewClient`.If not then you can do like below,

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

String currentUrl;

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {         
            currentUrl=url;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Here when you click on any link on the `WebView` then it will call `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` and you can get the current url there in `currentUrl`.

Comment: Note that `currentUrl` won't update on going back. The alternative is overriding `onPageStarted`.

Answer (score 2):

this is the most simple way of handling this for API > 20: There are obviously other methods with parsers like HTMLCleaner to have more control. However, this is good and simple for getting URL. Each time URL changes in Webview, URL in the request object changes as well.

```
@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            String temp  = request.getUrl().toString();
            if(temp.isEmpty()){
                Log.i(ActivityName, "No url returned!");
            }else{
                Log.i(ActivityName, temp);
            }
            return  false;
        }
```

you can also make your call by overriding onpagefinished method of webviewclient. I wanted to note this, since this is called when page finishes loading.

Answer (score 0):

**In Java this way :**

```
String js = "(function() { " +
        "return document.getElementById('my_element').innerHTML;" +
        "})()";

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        view.evaluateJavascript(js, new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                // 'value' contains the result of the JavaScript code
                Log.d("WebView", "Data: " + value);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**in Kotlin :**

```
    var js = "(function() { " +
                "return document.getElementById('my_element').innerHTML;" +
                "})()"
      webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
           override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            view.evaluateJavascript(jso) { value -> 
// 'value' contains  the result of the JavaScript code

            Log.d("WebView", "Data: $value")
        }
        }
            }
```

**Note**: `getElementsByClassName` can get value too.