# When I use from setWebChromeClient I can't use from onPageStarted webView - Android

Tags: android, webview, webchromeclient

I am using from below code for upload file in `webView` :

```
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private void loadWebView(String url) {
        if (getActivity() != null) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
            }

            WebSettings webSettings = webViewRequest.getSettings();

            webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webViewRequest.clearHistory();
            webViewRequest.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            webViewRequest.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

            webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
            webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);


            webViewRequest.loadUrl(url);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
                webViewRequest.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                webViewRequest.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                webViewRequest.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
            }
            webViewRequest.setWebViewClient(new Callback());

            webViewRequest.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                    super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                    if (newProgress == 100) {
                        if (progressRequestWebView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            progressRequestWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                }

                //For Android 3.0+
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                    mUM = uploadMsg;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("*/*");
                    WebViewRequestFragment.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FCR);
                }

                // For Android 3.0+, above method not supported in some android 3+ versions, in such case we use this
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                    mUM = uploadMsg;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("*/*");
                    WebViewRequestFragment.this.startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                            FCR);
                }

                //For Android 4.1+
                public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                    mUM = uploadMsg;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    i.setType("*/*");
                    WebViewRequestFragment.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), WebViewRequestFragment.FCR);
                }

                //For Android 5.0+
                @Override
                public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                        WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                        WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                    if (mUMA != null) {
                        mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                    }
                    mUMA = filePathCallback;
                    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        File photoFile = null;
                        try {
                            photoFile = createImageFile();
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            //Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                        }
                        if (photoFile != null) {
                            mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                        } else {
                            takePictureIntent = null;
                        }
                    }
                    Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                    Intent[] intentArray;
                    if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                        intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                    } else {
                        intentArray = new Intent[0];
                    }

                    Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
                    return true;
                }

            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Uri[] results = null;
            //Check if response is positive
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == FCR) {
                    if (null == mUMA) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (intent == null) {
                        //Capture Photo if no image available
                        if (mCM != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                        }
                    } else {
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if (dataString != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUMA = null;
        } else {
            if (requestCode == FCR) {
                if (null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

**And I need to use below code, when user touch on any link on webView but don't work** :

```
webViewRequest.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    if (url.contains("GetAttachment")) {
                        cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                        urlDown = url;
                        if (checkPermission()) {
                            startDownload(urlDown, cookies);
                        } else {
                            requestPermission();
                        }
                    }
                }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get clicked url in web view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527318/get-clicked-url-in-web-view-in-android)

Comment: @ ADM . Not work.

Comment: What bot work? Specify in question. You need to override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`.

Comment: I tested and don't get me any thing.

Answer (score 0):

I delete bellow lines and good work now :

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```