# How to get URL from long click links in a webview?

Tags: android, url, android-webview, long-click

I want to Create a Context Menu for web view in android. My problem is that I cant get the URL from the clicked link. I write this code for log the clicked link:

```
webView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {

            WebView webView1 = (WebView) v;
            WebView.HitTestResult hitTestResult = webView1.getHitTestResult();
            Log.i("LinkClicked", hitTestResult.getExtra());

            return false;
        }
    });
```

With this code, when long click on links in websites like *stackoverflow*, log like this:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions

everything is ok, but when long click on google search results, log like this:

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAAJFBMVEVHcEz/AAD/AAD/AAD/AAD/AAD/AAD/AAD/g4P/////KCj/7e0I8rGvAAAAB3RSTlMAT0g5Ggp+EilkVQAAAENJREFUGJVjYCAGsDAzggEzC5jLxo4E2BgYWNlRACsDM5jmggkwMzCBaQ5uqBATTICTk4OAAEILhqEY1mI4DNPphAAASIsES4gsgWgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

it does not return a link. How I can fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get clicked url in web view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527318/get-clicked-url-in-web-view-in-android)

Comment: @VikaSGuttE when using **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method in **setOnLongClickListener**, not log any thing.

Comment: try my below ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    String URL1 = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60577403/how-to-get-url-from-long-click-links-in-a-webview/60577736?noredirect=1#comment107173847_60577736";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                URL1 = url;
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(URL1);
        // Register the context menu for web view
        registerForContextMenu(webView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        // Get the web view hit test result
        final WebView.HitTestResult result = webView.getHitTestResult();

        // If user long press on url
        if (result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.ANCHOR_TYPE ||
                result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE) {

            // Set the title for context menu
            menu.setHeaderTitle("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t ◦ ◉ ⦿ Select ⦿ ◉ ◦ \t");

            // Add an item to the menu
            menu.add(0, 1, 0, " \t \t➤\t Show URL")
                    .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                            String Pressed_url = result.getExtra();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "URL is:-" + Pressed_url,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

> Download [Full Code](http://gestyy.com/w8FEmF) from github.
>
> **Output**

[image: Menu]  [image: URL]

Comment: this does not work when I long click on a link. just work when clicked on a link and web view loaded the link. I want when long click, get URL and use it for context menu, please look at this: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Lll.jpg)

Comment: I'm so sorry about this, but can you more explain? I log `clicked_url` but don't see anything: [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoE7Y.png)

Comment: @MartinBigot added full code with hope this will work...! enjoy coding, good luck.

Comment: thank you very very much! its work complete and correct. but still not return google search result URL. Search anything in google.com and long click on a site, its return a vague string. thank you for your attention...